# Type-ahead Bloodhound sort return values.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I am using Twitter type ahead but finding a difficultly to divide the results from mysql query.

My json output looks like this: {"id":"1","name":"Bravo"}

in the current state the results in typeahead are showing the name and the id , I would like to be able to show only the name but the actual submit value of the input to be the id. My script is the flowing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Instantiate the Bloodhound suggestion engine
var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: 'includes/livesearch.php?key=%QUERY',       
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        filter: function (name) {
            // Map the remote source JSON array to a JavaScript object array
            return $.map(name, function (name) {
                return {
                    value: name
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
// Initialize the Bloodhound suggestion engine
suggestions.initialize();

// Instantiate the Typeahead UI
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    minLength: 2
}, {
    limit: 7,
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: suggestions.ttAdapter(),
});
</script>
```

Any help or suggestions how I can achieve this are very welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object to store the current retrieved values. At `filter` option of `Bloodhound` set the object property to `name.name`, and value to `name.id`.

To return and display only `name` property of retrieved `JSON`, use the `index` parameter of `$.map()` to check the property name of the object. If the property is `"name"` return `{value:name}`, else return `null`.

Use `typeahead:selected` event to set the value of an `<input type="hidden">` element within the `<form>` using the current value of `.typeahead` `input` as a property reference at the previously stored object of initial return value at `filter`. Set variable reference which stores values to an empty object.

```
 <form>
   <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="search">
   <input type="hidden" name="result" value="" />
   <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

```
$(function() {
  // Instantiate the Bloodhound suggestion engine
  var curr = {};
  var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(datum) {
      return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: 'includes/livesearch.php?key=%QUERY',       
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        filter: function (name) {
          curr[name.name] = name.id;
            // Map the remote source JSON array to a JavaScript object array
            return $.map(name, function (name, index) {
                return index === "name" ? {
                    value: name
                } : null;
            });
        }
    }

  });
  // Initialize the Bloodhound suggestion engine
  suggestions.initialize();

  // Instantiate the Typeahead UI
  $(".typeahead").typeahead({
    hint: true,
    minLength: 2
  }, {
    limit: 7,
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: suggestions.ttAdapter(),
  })
  .on("typeahead:selected", function (e, datum) {
    $("form [name=result]").val(curr[datum.value]); // set value here
    curr = {};
  });
})
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/PJjzxemAQ9fO3P5YBfXi?p=preview

Comment: Works exactly the way I need ! Thank you very much !